# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, typeerror

I have this error while trying to run mediaelement player.

The error is reported at `mediaelement-and-player.min.js:44`.

Edit: My apologies, I posted this from the [mediaelementjs.com](http://mediaelementjs.com) Support website.

I was trying to use mediaelement.js to play audio on my website.

Edit 8/2: The interesting thing is that when i load the full `mediaelement-and-player.js` instead of the `minified` version, it works fine.

Comment: The object you are calling each on is undefined.

Comment: Please re-tag your question using the tags 'javascript', 'jquery' & 'undefined'.

Comment: It works with the development version, but not the minified version. so I'm not sure if the object I'm calling is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with this same issue while trying to use the Drupal module, http://drupal.org/project/mediaelement.

Turns out that a core Drupal javascript file, drupal.js, was calling jQuery.noConflict() which removes the $ variable from being defined in the global scope, hence bringing this bug in mediaelement-and-player.js to light.

This was reported in the issue queue for the mediaelement project and it looks like the fix just got committed: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/pull/570

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have not loaded the jquery library into your script.

You have to reference the library (a js file) from within the header of your page via url. The url can point to a copy pf jquery you keep local or to a public site.